# WindowsStoreApp Failed certification,saying the App failed Touch Input

Tags: wpf, events, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

My WindowsStoreApp certification failed(not the first submission) in Windows Store recently. The Note from testers says

```
The app is not usable with touch input and no such limitation is 
disclosed in the app description page. Please see: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh761498.aspx 
for some of the common interactions for keyboard, mouse and touch.
```

I dont have a Windows RT device to test, instead I test my App in a windows 8 PC. I used 'POINTER PRESSED' Event in my App for Navigations,calculations,etc. I had successfully uploaded this App to the store a lot of times,but this time it failed. I am confused. My App should support all sort of WindowsStore Devices.Please guide me.
[image: Certificaion Failure Image]

Comment: Did you try testing in [Windows 8 emulator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davrous/archive/2012/07/10/using-the-windows-8-simulator-amp-vs-2012-to-debug-the-ie10-touch-events-amp-your-responsive-design.aspx)? It does provide a nice touch input simulation.

Comment: Yes,I did in Windows 8 simulator using touch input simulation and its working fine.But haven't tried in Windows 8.1 simulator.

Comment: Testing in Windows 8 should suffice. Hard to guess what could be wrong without knowing the actual application. Does you application depend on keyboard? or do you have mouse hover behavior (like IE style menu)? Are you able to operate ur application end-to-end in simulator, without ever touching Keyboard or mouse (Arrow) pointer?

Comment: Yes,My app has Mouser over Event,but it just changes the color of the image(will not affect any functionality),Yes,I can operate all through my app without touching keypad/keyboard.